# Use gtest_main.a directly?

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest

The sample makefile of gtest has following line of code

```
gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc

gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
            $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc

gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
```

As I'm not making any changes to the files required by gtest_main.a can I use this gtest_main.a in all the MAkefiles directly without writing the steps to build it? I mean once the gtest_main.a has been generated I can always provide a path to it or copy paste in my project directory!

Comment: It's not clear whether you're talking about *files* or *rules*. Have you built `gtest_main.a`? If so, then as long as you don't modify its prerequisites, you don't need a rule for it. (Although why you want to avoid having a rule for it is a mystery to me.)

Comment: Im talking about the files. I feel it is unnecessary to build gtest_main.a again and again!

Comment: A well-written makefile will not rebuild a target unless the rebuilding is actually necessary; if yours is rebuilding the library over and over when you haven't modified the real prerequisites, then there's something wrong with your makefile. Do you have the same problem with `gtest-all.o` and/or `gtest_main.o`?

Comment: Thanks @Beta i almost forgot that!

Answer (score 1):

I tried using getst_main.a directly and it worked. Contrary to my belief that these lines should be eliminated to make the compilation faster, it actually doesn't matter. Makefile automatically detects if dependencies were modified, if not it skips the compilation of that file. Thanks Beta

Answer (score 0):

Go to your build configuration and add an environment variable for GTEST_DIR.
Solved my issue.